# mysqli: PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having some trouble with prepared statements. Basically, this query is returning no rows, even though I know for a fact that this query should return multiple rows. I thought this was just a problem due to SQL injections, but maybe I'm doing something else wrong here, I don't know. If I take out the check for how many rows there are, I get an error:

PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array()

Any help would be appreciated!

```
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT sid from SDS WHERE uid=? AND dst=?");

    $stmt->bind_param('ss',$username,$structureType);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($results);

    $stmt->fetch();

    if ($results) {

        if($results->num_rows == 0) {
            print("No results here.");
            return 0;
        }

        $recordnames = array();

        while ($next_row = $results->fetch_array()) {
               $recordnames[] = $next_row['sid'];
        }

        return $recordnames;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use $stmt->bind_result($result); you are binding the sid from the database to the variable $results. So you cannot perform operations like :

```
if($results->num_rows == 0) { //... }
```

or

```
$results->fetch_array();
```

This is how I would do it :

```
<?php

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT sid from SDS WHERE uid=? AND dst=?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $structureType);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($sid);
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows == 0) 
{
    print("No results here.");

    $stmt->close();

    return 0;
}
else
{
    $recordnames = array();

    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
        $recordnames[] = $sid;
    }

    return $recordnames;
}

?>
```

This way uses a different logic, check if the row count is 0, if so display "No results here", if not put results into the array.